# asp.net event handler not firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events

I've been looking for a solution to this for several hours now and cannot find a solution.

The Scenario:

- I have a masterpage baseclass (called basemaster)
- All of my master pages inherit from basemaster
- basemaster defines an event 'Public Event HandleClickEvent As EventHandler'
- I have a masterpage named master1
- master1 defines an event handler 'Public Shadows Event HandleClickEvent As EventHandler'
- master1 has a user control named usr1
- usr1 has a button that raises event ButtonClicked when clicked
- I have a page (thePage) that uses master1
- thePage has a button click event handler that it registers like so: 'AddHandler Master.HandleClickEvent, AddressOf HandleTheClick'
- master1 has code something like:

  Protected Sub Usr1_ButtonClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Usr1.ButtonClicked
      RaiseEvent HandleClickEvent(sender, e)
  End Sub
- when thePage loads I see it register the handler on master1
- when the button is clicked, Usr1_ButtonClicked is fired and I step through the RaiseEvent but HandleClickEvent on thePage is never reached.

I think I'm doing something stupid.  I would appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does the event on your master page class need to be an actual event handler? You should be able to just make it a public method and access it from your page (or user control) event handler like this:

```
Page.Master.MyPublicMasterPageMethod()
```

To call a method on your content page from your master page you could use VB's CallByName method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22x2chfx.aspx

Comment: OK... I'm not sure I know what you mean.  How does the fired event from the master pages button then call the handler on the page?  Sorry... a little lost.

Comment: See my updated answer to make a call in going the other direction (from master page to content page)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give that a try... but I am still very curious why the event handler isn't firing... like there is something I'm missing.